# Apply Solr filter query to only part of the search results

Tags: solr, filter, grouping

I have a Solr solution working which requires two queries, but I'm looking for a way to do it in a single query.  My idea is that if I can figure out a way to do this, I wont have to incur the overhead of twice the load on the Solr cluster.

The details: I'm running a simple query like "q=camera" with a query filter of say "fq=type:digital". The second query is identical to the first, but the filter is the inverse, like "fq=-type:digital"  I'm imagining that if there's a way to run a single query while applying the first filter to get the first set of topDocs, then generate a second set with the second filter the results could be merged and returned ( it doesn't matter if sorting resorts and mixes the two sets).

I experimented with partitioning the data by marking a specific field during indexing, into two different groups and then using Solr "grouping" queries, but the response time for these wasn't acceptable in my setup.

I'm looking for suggestions the most Solr congruent approach to experiment with: tuning to improve the two-query solution performance, or investigating a kind of custom Solr post-filter ( I read Yonik's 2/2012 blog post ).

I have to implement this in Solr 3.5, although if there's a slam dunk solution in 4.0 I'll eventually be able to move to that.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two alternate approaches :-

1. Instead of filter the results, use a variable higher boost so that all the results for `type:digital` come on top and rest of the documents would follow. No need for separate queries. The boost can be changes as per the type value.
2. Other approach is not to display the results for type other then digital. However, you can display the facets for the other types with the counts for the same for users to know if the other types exist for the search term. You can check on [tagging and excluding filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters)

Answer (score 0):

[Result grouping](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) might give you what you want. Just group by that parameter and specify sufficient top number of documents in each group.

But I would test whether its performance is any better than two queries. Just because it mentions performance in limitations section.